# Read midi files

Tags: c++, file-io, midi

I found http://midifile.sapp.org/ this library is reading and creating midi files, but it's reading only standard 1.0 midis.
Is there way to modify this or is there another library in C++?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=C%2B%2B+midi+library

Comment: @Photon: Better yet, http://bit.ly/1aexNb8

Answer (score 1):

Actually, since you have made this post they have added functionality for Midi Type 0, 1, and 2. Also, if you store the midi file as an object (which is standard protocol for using the Midifile library, as I am sure you are aware) you can also programmatically convert the .mid file into a any type of midi file, such as 0 to 2 etc. and save it as well.

If you're wanting to move onto greener pastures though, I would *seriously consider* using the libs provided by the OpenMidiProject, spearheaded by Kuzu. You'll have to navigate around some Japanese text (he *is* in Japan after all), but really, this library is the bee's knees and then some.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might have a look at libwildmidi.